# PHP, While Loop a Table to show results from a database

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli

I am having a problem trying to get a row to create everytime I enter a new database entry.

My code so far is:

```
<table align="center">
    <th>MH/s</th><th>Contact Length</th><th>Date Bought</th><th>Payment</th>

<?php while ($row_cnt > 0) {
    echo "<tr><td>" . $row['mhbought'] . "</td><td>" . $row['length'] . "</td><td>" . date(d-m-Y, $row['datebought'] . "</  td><td>" . $row['payment'] . "</td></tr>";
}
?>
</table>
```

The error I receive however states `PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected ';'` (which is the echo line) Am I doing something completely dumb here, can this even be done?

Thank you for any help you may provide.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the code, the problematic line is this:

```
date(d-m-Y, $row['datebought']
      ^^ missing quotes       ^ missing closing parenthesis
```

Change it to:

```
date('d-m-Y', $row['datebought'])
```

Answer (score 1):

You haven't close `date()` right bracket and there is quotation missing for date format. Your echo should look like:

```
echo "<tr><td>" . $row['mhbought'] . "</td><td>" . $row['length'] . "</td><td>" . date('d-m-Y', $row['datebought']) . "</td><td>" . $row['payment'] . "</td></tr>";
```